# How to fetch data from app registrations in Azure with status which says expiring soon

Tags: bash, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I would like to fetch data of apps from app registrations of which certificates with status are expiring soon.

If anyone could help with PowerShell script or any other way of fetching the data please help

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried with the above requirement and able to fetch the details of certificate and secrets which will expire soon.

***PowerShell script:-***

```
Connect-AzureAD
$expiresWithinDays = 31
$expired = Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true | ForEach-Object {
$app = $_
@(
Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $_.ObjectId
Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $_.ObjectId
) | Where-Object {
$_.EndDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($expiresWithinDays)
} | ForEach-Object {
$id = "Not set"
if($_.CustomKeyIdentifier) {
$id = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($_.CustomKeyIdentifier)
}
[PSCustomObject] @{
App = $app.DisplayName
ObjectID = $app.ObjectId
AppId = $app.AppId
Type = $_.GetType().name
KeyIdentifier = $id
EndDate = $_.EndDate
}
}
}

$expired | Out-GridView
```

***SAMPLE OUTPUT:-***
[image]
[image]
[image]

For more information please refer this [***Blog***](https://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-audit-expiring-soon-azure-ad-application-credentials-keys-passwords-certificates/).