# How to retrieve thumbprint expiry date of enterprises application in azuread

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, saas

How to retrieve thumbprint expiry date of enterprises application in the azure ad using PowerShell in CSV format

```
Clear-Variable  diskreport3 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If($connect -eq $null){$connect = Connect-AzureAD }

$allService = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal


ForEach ($i in $allService)
{

Clear-Variable  Thumbprint -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$details = Get-AzureADServicePrincipalKeyCredential -ObjectId $i.ObjectID
$CustomKeyIdentifier = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipalKeyCredential -ObjectId $i.ObjectID).CustomKeyIdentifier
if($CustomKeyIdentifier -eq $null ){$Thumbprint = $null}
else{
$Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CustomKeyIdentifier)
}


$app=$i.displayname
$start = $details.StartDate
$end = $details.EndDate
$type = $details.Type

$dataRow = "
</tr>
<td>$app</td>
<td>$start</td>
<td>$end</td>
<td>$Thumbprint</td>
<td>$type</td>
</tr>
"
$diskreport3 += $datarow
}


$report = "<html>
<style>
{font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt;}
TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; font-size:13pt;}
TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; color: #000000;}
TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
</style>
<h2>Azure Service Principal details  </h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>APP</th>
<th>Startdate</th>
<th>EndDate</th>
<th>Thumbprint</th>
<th>Type</th>
</tr>
$diskreport3
</table>
<tr>
"

$report | Out-File "C:\temp\Azuread\data.html"
```

I tried this but I am not getting a proper thumbprint.
thumbprint is different in AzureAd

actually, the requirement is in CSV we need App name start date expiry date and thumbprint

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried so far and the issues you’re running into.

Comment: do you mean certificate thumbprint by thumbprint?

Comment: yes @RahulKumarShaw-MT

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell script to get Thumbprint and Their Expiry Time.

```
$expired  =  Get-AzureADApplication  -All:$true  |  ForEach-Object {
$app  =  $_
@(
Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential  -ObjectId  $_.ObjectId
$CustomKeyIdentifier  = (Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential  -ObjectId  $_.ObjectID).CustomKeyIdentifier
)|  Where-Object {
$_.EndDate }|  ForEach-Object {
$id  =  "Not set"
if($CustomKeyIdentifier) {
$id  =  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CustomKeyIdentifier)
}
[PSCustomObject] @{
App =  $app.DisplayName
ObjectID =  $app.ObjectId
AppId =  $app.AppId
Type =  $_.GetType().name
KeyIdentifier =  $id
EndDate =  $_.EndDate
}
}
}
$expired  |  Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv'
```

**Output:**
[image]

Reference : [bash - How to fetch data from app registrations in Azure with status which says expiring soon - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958273/how-to-fetch-data-from-app-registrations-in-azure-with-status-which-says-expirin/71018190#71018190)