# Get expiration date of signing certificate(s) within a SAML metadata file

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

I have about 30 SAML configurations from various vendors, all are metadata files that reside on the internet (Azure AD, Auth0 and a couple other identity providers).

Is there a tool that exists to extract the expiration date from the signing cert in the metadata file? So I can keep track of all the expiration? Preferably a CLI.

Comment: if you code, you can use Java X509Certificate and x509Cert.getNotAfter(). Or you could try the steps in this tutorial https://uwnthesis.wordpress.com/2019/05/17/shibboleth-saml-how-extract-expiry-date-of-a-certificate-from-the-xml-file/

Comment: Check this link it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464037/how-to-retrieve-thumbprint-expiry-date-of-enterprises-application-in-azuread

Answer (score 0):

For workaround you can use this powershell command to get the expiry time of siging certificate that is uploaded in Azure AD application.

Based on your requirements you can edit the code and pull the certificate from metafiles rather than directly from AzureAD application.

```
$expired  =  Get-AzureADApplication  -All:$true  |  ForEach-Object {
$app  =  $_
@(
Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential  -ObjectId  $_.ObjectId
$CustomKeyIdentifier  = (Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential  -ObjectId  $_.ObjectID).CustomKeyIdentifier
)|  Where-Object {
$_.EndDate }|  ForEach-Object {
$id  =  "Not set"
if($CustomKeyIdentifier) {
$id  =  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CustomKeyIdentifier)
}
[PSCustomObject] @{
App =  $app.DisplayName
ObjectID =  $app.ObjectId
AppId =  $app.AppId
Type =  $_.GetType().name
KeyIdentifier =  $id
EndDate =  $_.EndDate
}
}
}
$expired  |  Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv
```

[image]

***Reference : [How to retrieve thumbprint expiry date of enterprises application in azuread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464037/how-to-retrieve-thumbprint-expiry-date-of-enterprises-application-in-azuread)***